# PHP Missing Slashes

Tags: php

I am convinced that the solution is very simple, however I have searched many pages and questions and I am slightly frustrated with the lack of solution. 
I'm trying to create a span element which has the onclick property.
The onclick event should pass to the displayStory function path to the text file.
Unfortunately, all slashes are missing.
Slashes are fine if I dont use apostrophes inside $dir, however i have to insert them somehow

PHP:

```
 <?php
            $allStories = scandir("./stories");
            foreach($allStories as $story){
                $dir = "'/stories/$story'";
                $element =  ("<span class='listElement' onclick='displayStory($dir)'>$story</span>");
                echo $element;
            }
      ?>
```

Output:

```
<span class="listElement" onclick="displayStory(" stories="" example.txt')'="">example.txt</span>
```

Comment: `$dir` contains slashes, which you need to escape, among other potential invalid characters in this context. Take a look at `htmlspecialchars`. Also, using `onclick` is quite outdated, look into [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: _“Output:”_ - so the single quotes in your PHP code, magically morphed into double quotes in the output …?

Comment: Thanks for that, and answering @04FS... yes they did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to escape characters:

```
<?php
     $allStories = scandir("./stories");
     foreach($allStories as $story){
          // No single quotes here
          $dir = "/stories/$story";
          // No parenthesis needed to assign a value
          // Escape double quotes for attributes preceding them with a backslash \"
          // Use single quotes for function parameter
          $element = "<span class=\"listElement\" onclick=\"displayStory('$dir');\">$story</span>";
          echo $element;
     }
?>
```

Output should be:

```
<span class="listElement" onclick="displayStory('stories/example.txt');">example.txt</span>
```